# Define Android animation without using xml

Tags: android, animation

How can I define this animation xml by java code without using xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="900" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, why not ?

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet( true );
Animation translate = new TranslateAnimation( -100, 0, 0, 0); 
translate.setDuration( 900 );
set.addAnimation( translate );
```

Regards,
  Stéphane